# How to send email to yahoo via PHP

Tags: php, email

I am attempting to send a confirmation email from a PHP script. I tested on gmail and it worked fine (the email was sent with appropriate subject and contents), however when I tried sending an email to a yahoo account, the subject field was correct but the contents were sent as an attachment as opposed to text inside the actual email. Here is the mailing code.

```
$headers = 'From: ' . 'orders@COMPANY_NAME.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . 'orders@COMPANY_NAME.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "BCC: orders@COMPANY_NAME.com \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"
mail($email, "COMPANY_NAME Order Confirmation $confirmation_number", $text, $headers);
```

How can I send an email to yahoo that will include $text inside the email as opposed to an attachment?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe it's due to the extra `\r\n` at the end of the headers.

Comment: Extra \r\n? Do you mean in the Content-Type? I deleted it and the problem persists.

Comment: That's the one I mean. They seemed obsolete, and I thought they might interfere. But like I said, it was a guess. Glad I didn't post it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because of a wrong "Content-Type" header: I do not think "text" is a valid content type.
You should try, instead, with "text/plain".

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

PS: you may also want to consider using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1.